# Feed has_many Products, before_save on both makes them hang

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Feed model, which downloads a file, then creates products from the Product model.

I have a before_save that starts the feed download process (when the new Feed form is submitted), and creates the new products. Then I have a before_save on the Product model that downloads a remote photo, as well as calculating a few other things.

However, instead of:

- I click submit
- Feed begins downloading
- Creates products, downloads images, runs calculations
- Flashes "Feed successfully downloaded"

It just hangs, nothing much happens. Feed doesn't download, products don't go into the database.

Is there a known way to "daisy-chain" before-saves?

Any help appreciated :)

Thanks,

Geoff

Answer (score 1):

before_save is maybe the wrong place. sounds like you need to do it in before_create.

btw:
i think the architecture is wrong. of your model based on remote data etc. i would create it asynchronly. that means: when you click on "create" and the http-connect hangs up, there is a failure.

better will be: create just the object. make a cronjob (or any other jobs) which takes the new elements and process them (remote downloads etc). so the remote-downloads are in the background (and i think in a good archtecture this is the right place for them).

i do the same with imports. just create the importer (and upload the file). but the real importing (or working on the file) needs to be asynchron in a background job